# How to add text with sed at the end-of-line minus 1 position

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to add the text `[*,test,*]` just before the last character of a line starting with `resourceFilters:` in the input file (that string can be preceded by any number of spaces).

An example of this line is the following

```
resourceFilters: '[Event,*,*][*,kube-system,*][*,kube-public,*][*,kube-node-lease,*][Node,*,*][APIService,*,*][TokenReview,*,*][SubjectAccessReview,*,*][Binding,*,*][ReplicaSet,*,*]'
```

which would be changed into this:

```
resourceFilters: '[Event,*,*][*,kube-system,*][*,kube-public,*][*,kube-node-lease,*][Node,*,*][APIService,*,*][TokenReview,*,*][SubjectAccessReview,*,*][Binding,*,*][ReplicaSet,*,*][*,test,*]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
sed "/^ *resourceFilters: '/s/'$/[*,test,*]'/" your_file
```

- I've double quoted the Sed command so that I can use single quotes in it;
- `/^resourceFilters: '/` makes the following `s`ubstitution command only act on lines starting with `resourceFilters: '`;
- `s/'$/[*,test,*]'/` is the substitution command which matches `'` at end of line (`$`), and substitutes `[*, test,*]'` to it, effectively inserting `[*,test,*]` before the `'`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(\s*resourceFilters:.*)(.)$/\1[*,test,*]\2/' file
```

Match on a line containing `resourceFilters:` and insert `[*,test,*]` before the last character of the line.